# ctypes returns wrong type in Python

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

I am trying to call method from DLL file using python 2.7

My code is below:

```
import ctypes
myDll = ctypes.CDLL("K:\\Development\\Dll_Test\\xx.dll")

myDll.myMethod.argtypes=[ctypes.c_char_p]
myDll.myMethod.restype=ctypes.c_char_p
appId=ctypes.c_char_p('XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX')

challenge= myDll.myMethod(appId)
```

In DLL file, myMethod returns to *char but it returns to empty string in python.

What can be the problem?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: I can't find anything obviously wrong.  If you get an empty string it means that `myMethod` did return an empty `char *` (i.e. a pointer to a null character).

Comment: Shouldn't it be a c_char_p object?